# Getting the full referral URL from Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, url

I have looked how to find this information and all I can find is old information on how to do it which doesn't work now, such as: http://www.sebastienpage.com/2009/05/06/google-analytics-trick-see-the-full-referring-url/

I manged to find the `User Defined` selection in the "Behavior" section, but when I clicked on it all I get is "not set".

How can I get the full referrer URL from Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

You question is not very clear. Hopefully this helps:

- 'hostname' - full domain name of the requested page
- 'request uri' - relative URL

Example:
http://www.google-analytics.com/requestURL/index.html?sample=text

- hostname = 'http://www.google-analytics.com'
- request uri = 'requestURL/index.html?sample=text '

Comment: Yeah... put the two together and that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the tactic from http://www.sebastienpage.com/2009/05/06/google-analytics-trick-see-the-full-referring-url/ *did* work; however it *only* works on data *after* you input this filter, not on existing data.